# Getting a deprecation warning, and suggesting to use what I am using in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am using a method is suggesting, but giving me a warning not to use it, suggesting the same method. What?

```
// Upgrade stats query
  if (args.type === "stats") {
    const user = await User.findById(args.id, (err, res) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }).then(user => {
      return user;
    });
    if ((await user.meta.statpoints) > 1) {
      let query;
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: args.id },
        {
          $inc: {
            "meta.currency.cs": 1
          }
        },
        (err, user) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
      ).then(user => {
        //console.log(user.meta.currency);
      });
    }
  }
```

It is giving me this warning:
`(node:1360) DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.`

I mean its not a huge deal, but it is kind of weird it is doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useFindAndModify is true by default, so you can set it to false globally
`mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);`

or with connection
 `mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false });`